# Execute Selenium script on EC2 Windows Server running a Flask site on Windows Server 2012

Tags: python, selenium, flask, amazon-ec2, server

I'm currently building a Selenium script that executes on Windows Server 2012 (through EC2). This script needs to execute whenever an API endpoint is reached. Our website needs to connect to the API Endpoint (FLASK on the Windows Server) and then execute a Selenium Script held locally within that server.

Website > Flask Website > Executes Selenium Script.

This works when running Locally on my Macbook Pro. This also works when running locally on the Windows Server. However, when running it though IIS with WFASTCGI, it just doesn't do anything on the server. Protected mode is disabled. Firewall is disabled.

FLASK Site:

```
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime
from subprocess import Popen
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
import os

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/")
@app.route("/index")
def index():
    return "This is Index"

@app.route("/run_batch")
def run_batch():
    # Setup default variables
    process = os.system('C:/Python/Projects/czech_data_scripts/selenium/main.py')
    process.communicate()
    return "This is run_batch"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "******* START *******"
    start_time = datetime.now()

    app.run()

    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print "******* END *******"
```

Selenium Script:

```
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print "******* START *******"
    start_time = datetime.now()

    # Setup default variables
    browser = webdriver.Ie("C:/IEDriverServer.exe")
    browser.get("http://www.google.com")

    end_time = datetime.now()
    print('Duration: {}'.format(end_time - start_time))
    print "******* END *******"
```

IIS Logs (IPs removed FYI):

```
#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-09-10 12:35:43
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-09-10 12:35:43 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET / - 80 - xx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 843
2018-09-10 12:35:43 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /favicon.ico - 80 - xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 http://ec2.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ 404 0 0 93
2018-09-10 12:36:13 xx.xxx.xxx.xxx GET /run_batch - 80 - xx.xxx.xxx.xxx Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 25563

#Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 10.0
#Version: 1.0
#Date: 2018-09-10 13:51:27
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) cs(Referer) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2018-09-10 13:51:27 xxx.xx.xx.xxx GET / - 80 - xx.xx.xxx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 200 0 0 1265
2018-09-10 13:51:27 xxx.xx.xx.xxx GET /favicon.ico - 80 - xx.xx.xxx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 http://ec2.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com/ 404 0 0 140
2018-09-10 13:51:59 xxx.xx.xx.xxx GET /run_batch - 80 - xx.xx.xx.xx Mozilla/5.0+(Macintosh;+Intel+Mac+OS+X+10_13_6)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/68.0.3440.106+Safari/537.36 - 500 0 0 28203
```

**Edit**: Tried migrating the script into the the run_batch function but this returns HTTP Error 500. This works on Localhost however. Feel like there is a misconfiguration in IIS.

Comment: There is too little information to give you a hand.
Add some logs to see:
Is the endpoint of  Flask app triggered ?
If yes - is the Selenium process run ?
Check logs for potential errors, for example IIS logs

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov I'll attach logs now. There's not really much going on in them.

Comment: @Andrew_Lvov I've attached the logs. They're small because each block is essentially the same

Comment: So, uhhm, what about questions in my first comment? Does the endpoint get triggered ?